# RelativeLayout not showing items to the left

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've got what I think is a simple layout.  This contains a scroll view, within that a horizontal scroll view so I can scroll both ways.  I've simplified the example so all it has is a RelativeLayout containing one TextView and another RelativeLayout.  Here is the XML:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" 
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:text="TEXT LABEL" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/myText">
                     <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
                        android:text="2"/>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1"/>
                     <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                        android:text="3"/>                       
           </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

I can see button 1 and 3 but I'm not seeing button 2.  I need to do it this way unfortunately because the page is built dynamically (this xml is a simplified version of what I am doing) and I only know what I need to be left of.  I had it working at one point but had to re-arrange some other code and it broke.  What am I missing?

Here's a link to a snapshot: [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcSyH.jpg)

Comment: can you post a link to a picture of how it appears now?

Comment: Where should button 2 be placed?

Comment: button2 should be aligned with the top left corner of button1.  I know I can align button1 with the bottom,  right corner of button2 but I need to build it this way.

Answer (score 0):

button2 is off the screen to the top left of button1.

I'm not sure what your expected result is, however you could try anchoring button2 to the top left (layout_alignParentTop, layout_alignParentLeft) then show button1 to the right or below it depending on what you want.

Here is an example of that if you just want button1 to the right of button2:

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                android:text="3" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Depends on what you are actually trying to do (I'm confused by android:layout_above="@+id/button1" AND  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" in button2)

Comment: The above and toLeftOf will put button2 on the top left corner of button1.